# Why do these two comparisons have different results?

Tags: c#, .net, equality

Why does this code return true:

```
new Byte() == new Byte()   // returns true
```

but this code returns false:

```
new Byte[0] == new Byte[0] // returns false
```

Comment: See http://ericlippert.com/2014/01/15/inconsistent-equality/

Comment: I am surprised no one found duplicates for this question, as it is very basic **value** type verses **reference** type question.

Comment: I am even more surprised by the number of up-votes it has got - 51 as of now.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Because `new Byte()` creates value type, which are compared by value (by default it will return `byte` with value `0`). And `new Byte[0]` creates array, which is a reference type and compared by reference (and these two instances of array will have different references).

See [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) article for details.

Answer (score 43):

Bytes are [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) in .NET, meaning that the `==` operator returns true if and only if the two bytes have the same value. This is also known as [*value equality*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183755.aspx).

But arrays are [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) in .NET, meaning the `==` operator returns true if and only if they refer to the same array instance in memory. This is also known as [*reference equality* or *identity*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183759.aspx).

Note that the `==` operator can be overloaded for both reference and value types. `System.String`, for example, is a reference type, but the `==` operator for strings compares each character in the array in sequence. See [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

If you want to test whether the arrays *contain* exactly the same values (in order) you should consider using [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `==`.

Comment: I believe the crux of the question is about the `==` operator and its dual nature.  This answer clearly covers that.

Comment: I like the use of "by default" for other reference types, but is it actually possible to change this behavior for array types?

Comment: @ChrisHayes No. Operators may only be overloaded within the class(es) they are defined for, and since the `System.Array` class doesn't provide an overload, it uses the default, reference equality. You might think you could create your own array type (`System.Array` is abstract after all), but the compiler doesn't allow you to inherit from it. You could probably come fairly close with some subtle use of implicit operators to cast the array to another type, though, but the very idea makes my skin crawl.

Answer (score 10):

comparing reference is actually comparing pointer address, which are different that is the reason returning false and in value address not matter it compares value.

Compiler try to store Value type in registers but due to limited registers number further storage happens in Stack with values [[Reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3822717/821057) while Reference type is in stack but value holding a address of memory address in Heap.

Comparison here compare the value present in stack which is in first case for both same while in second case it is addresses of heap which are different.

> [image: reference]

Comment: This is a pretty confusing answer. The first part still makes it look like a reference comparison, because you still use the word "Pointer". The use of the graphic versus just text is also annoying because it makes it very difficult for me to edit it to improve the answer.

Comment: -1 for perpetuating the "value types are stored in the stack" myth. I'd have thought it quite likely that the results of those two `new Byte()` calls are probably stored in registers.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Register storage depends on register availability else it store in Stack, in both cases  value is same.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx for a full explanation.

Comment: Your whole answer is still a ramble. The key aspect of value types is that they are compared by value. It doesn't matter **where** that value is stored. You can place two value types into heap-allocated structures (either deliberately or due to hoisting) and the comparisons will still be based on their value.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of the `==` operator in which both operands are of type `byte` and it is implemented to compare the value of each byte; in this case you have two zero bytes, and they are equal.

The `==` operator isn't overloaded for arrays, so the overload having two `object` operands is used (since arrays are of type `object`) in the second case, and its implementation compares the references to the two objects.  The reference to the two arrays are different.

It's worth noting that this has nothing (directly) to do with the fact that `byte` is a value type and arrays are reference types.  The `==` operator for `byte` has value semantics *only* because there is a specific overload of the operator with that implementation.  If that overload did not exist then there would *be* no overload for which two bytes would be valid operands, and as such the code *wouldn't compile at all*.  You can see this easily enough by creating a custom `struct` and comparing two instances of it with the `==`operator.  The code will not compile, unless you provide your own implementation of `==` for those types.